# Snackbar over Dialog with MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React with the [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) library, and have the following component hierarchy:

```
<RootContainer>
  <SnackBar />
  <HomeContainer>
    <LoginModal />
  </HomeContainer>
</RootContainer>
```

My issue is that the Snackbar shows up underneath the LoginModal, even when its zIndex is increased to `9999`.

[image]

What's the correct way to place the Snackbar *over* the modal (or more precisely, over the backdrop of the Modal?

Comment: MaterialUI is just following Google's material design guidelines regarding the respective elevation of elements. I don't understand why you would want to put a validation/error message in the snackbar anyway, it belongs on the form?

Comment: Have you checked this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071435/set-component-z-index-on-custom-theme-in-material-ui

Answer (score 26):

The best way that I found was using Portal to wrap around the Snackbar component
https://material-ui.com/api/portal/.

Just render your snackbar as child of portal that's it:

```
<Portal>
 <SnackBar/> 
<Portal/>
```

This way you can get a Snackbar on top of the Dialog's opaque background

Answer (score 2):

Which version of material-ui are you using?  I'm unable to reproduce this in the latest v1-beta: https://codesandbox.io/s/084v1z2qn

I've also tried reproducing this with v0.x to no avail.

If you're using v0.x, check your theme.  [Snackbar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/snackbar) uses a value defined in the `zIndex` attribute (see [implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/src/Snackbar/Snackbar.js)).  From the [defaults](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3ba7b3ffdb2d5a819f6b0b0ce166f206d39a182b/src/styles/zIndex.js), you can see that `snackbar` is higher than `modal`.

Check the values of `theme.zIndex.snackbar` and `theme.zIndex.modal`.  Snackbar should be higher.  If this isn't the case, you've customized the theme from its default and can simply change your theme.

If the theme looks right, check the styles and classes you've applied to the Dialog, Snackbar, Modal, etc.  I mention this because your question mentions an attempt at setting Snackbar's `z-index` to `999`.  The theme defaults `modal` to `1300`, so a value of `999`, as specified in your question, would be too low.  If you've messed with `z-index`, you're no longer relying on the theme configuration, so your mistake could be there.

Since both release branches of material-ui handle z-index by default and this problem cannot be easily reproduced, I'm pretty sure the problem is in your styling.

Feel free to include a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) with a reproducible case and I'll take another look.

Comment: The answer is insufficient. I'm suffering from the same problem, checking z-index showed modal 1300 and snackbar 1400 - although snackbar is behind the backdrop which has z-index -1 - all MUI defaults. and no customization of the themes at all. I worked around that by changing the flow which isn't a solution for the OP here.

Comment: Given the information provided, this is what I was able to provide.  See the parts where I mention their incorrect use of a 999 z-index, list possible causes, and request a reproducible example.  It seems like you’re confident that you have a handle on OP’s problem without any additional information, so it would be more productive if you just helped them.  Feel free to post an answer that sufficiently answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with Snackbar hidden behind backdrop of a drawer.
Fixed that by putting Snackbar component after the main view renders in the React DOM. In my App it looks like this:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <IntlProvider locale={lang} messages={messages[lang]}>
      <React.Fragment>
        {configRoutes()}
          <SnackbarMsg
            open={props.snackbarOpen}
            msg={props.snackbarMsg}
            success={props.snackbarSuccess}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      </IntlProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

It should be fine to create and use HOC for that and I will probably go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is that because modals are siblings to root. HTML Layering is hierarchical, so even though dialog's z-index is higher, those are never used for comparison:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12044

I am likely going to just going to add a snackbar in my dialogs, but let me know if anyone has a good solution for a global snackbar.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).